# Error en la conexión de la base de datos del hosting en laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, hosting, deployment

Tengo un problema al hacer un deployment de laravel, al subir el proyecto e intentar usarlo me toma los valores de la base de datos local y no los que configuro en el .env del laravel, me da el siguiente error:

```
PDOException in Connector.php line 55: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "127.0.0.1", user "xxxx", database "xxxxx", SSL off
```

El .env esta bien configurado pero no logro ver porque me mantiene los datos de la base de datos local... Agradecería la ayuda.

Comment: En el archivo `database.php` a que BD tienes como `'default'`?

Comment: Si: 'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'pgsql'),

Comment: Y en ese mismo archivo `database.php` la conexión de `'pgsql'` esta bien configurado también?

Comment: Los datos de conexion estan configurado en el .env que es el archivo que guarda los datos, en este archivo estan los datos por defectos

Comment: Si el archivo .env está bien configurado y estás definiendo el ambiente correcto en APP_ENV, lo más probable es que sea un problema de caché de la aplicación, si no puedes ejecutar los comandos de artisan, borra el contenido de storage/framework/cache y storage/framework/session, asumiendo que administres la caché y la sesión con archivos.

Comment: Ya borre esos archivos y nada, me parece muy extraño porque pareciera que no esta leyendo los datos del .env y esta tomando los datos de conexion en otro lado, pero ni idea... alguna otra sugerencia?

Comment: Como estas haciendo el deploy? estas seguro que esta consiguiendo leer el archivo .env?

Comment: Saludos, había abandonado el punto, pero necesito resolverlo!! Alguien alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Maru, estoy haciendo el deploy colocando la carpeta public en una carpeta, la index de sub dominio de mi hosting y los demas archivos en otra carpeta... no se que mas mirar, pero me sigue mostrando los datos locales en el hosting